# Opening additional XPage databases throws error 500 in XPiNC

Tags: xpages

We have a number of different instances of the same XPage design on various servers. Users may access them either locally or on the server, always using XPages in the Notes Client. If they have one of these open, and double-click on another to open it in the client, it throws an Error 500. According to the log viewer (HelP>Support>View Log), it seems to be a null pointer exception:

CLFAD0256E: Dispatcher Servlet Problem - java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NullPointerException

No details get shown in the status bar and nothing else indicates to me why it's failed or what the null pointer is about.

If I remain in the same database and open a second window for the same database from one of my links within the XPages, I don't get an error. If I close the first database and then open the second one, I don't get an error.

We do use applicationScope and viewScope variables, but I would surprised if those are somehow competing in memory. They might be, but I would be surprised.

I'm going to try launching with the client console to see if it provides more clues (-RPARAMS -console in the startup command), but am curious what others think I ought to be looking for, or if anyone else has had two XPages databases react this way.

The xpages.log contents:

```
6/4/14 1:41 PM: Internal warning: Check access being called outside of a request
6/4/14 1:41 PM: Internal warning: Check access being called without a valid session/database
6/4/14 1:42 PM: Internal warning: Check access being called outside of a request
6/4/14 1:42 PM: Internal warning: Check access being called without a valid session/database
6/4/14 1:42 PM: Exception Thrown
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.websrv.servlets.DispatcherServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pvc.webhttpservice.BridgeServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.http.HttpConnection.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.initModule(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.createNSFModule(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.loadModule(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.config.BootStrap.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.config.ConfigureCoreListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.checkJar(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$5.rtJarLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.findResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.digester(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Are servers set as trusted servers to each other in Domino Directory?

Comment: Even when both databases are on local, the error still occurs, so I don't think that's the issue. Nonetheless, the server documents are set to trust all servers in the organization, */MyCompany.

Comment: Get full stacktrace from file xpages.log in data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT directory.

Comment: Just created another database with nothing in it, and no error thrown when opening that XPage, so something in our design is the problem.

Comment: sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.checkJar - seems missing JAR, check project build settings/paths

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth, but why would it be missing the JAR only whenever another instance of the same design is already open. Closing that instance and reopening the second one works without error.

Comment: Are you preloading the XPages application? Also, is there something wrong with the ECL settings or sessionAsSigner being used with different signers? I think the "Internal warning" are standard for XPiNC, so not the cause. I think it's the NullPointerException, but it's not clear from the stack trace what is causing that?

Comment: What if different servers have diferent version of the same JAR? replication/ACL issue, for example

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but when opening two instances on the same server, both refreshed from the same template built on my local, the second instance always throws the same error. So, I am attempting to add one component at a time to a blank database to see when it starts failing the same way. I'm sure it's something foolish, but once I figure it out, will post as an answer.

Comment: @DavidNavarre Any update on this question? I encounter it frequently when adding third party Jars to my NSF, which given my deployment model would be the preferred place to "stage" Jars but given the intermittent 500 errors makes it untenable.